# Spring Boot JmsListener blocked by other JmsListener for different destination

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-jms

I encountered the following situation in a Spring Boot application with JMS over ActiveMQ 5 as broker.

A `@JMSListener` annotated method processes a message and sends a response message to a different destination. There is also a `@JMSListener` for this destination, which is not called when the response has been sent to the broker, but only when the processing of the original listner is completely finished. If this listener is additionally annotated with `@Async`, the reponse is received immediately after sending as expected.

The original project is way too big, so I prepared the minimal example below.
It contains a Spring Boot application `TestApp` with a single `@JmsListener` *(1)* which immediately forwards a message from Destination *in* to *out* and *afterwards* sleeps for 3 seconds.

The application is started in a test which sends a single message to *in* and waits for 2 seconds for the response on *out*.

Only if the `@Async` is present at *(1)* the test is successful.

Further observations:

- Same behaviour if the test uses variant *(2)* and receives the response via `JmsTemplate` instead using a `JmsListener`.
- In any case one can see that the message is present in the broker immediately after sending.

**Question**: Why is receiving self-sent messages blocked in this situation? How can the outgoing message be received immediately without using `@Async`?

**Update/Solution**: As Gary suggested there is indeed a transaction present but seemingly not of Spring Boot but one created by the included activemq-lib.

```java
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.output.Slf4jLogConsumer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.LogMessageWaitStrategy;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApp.class, webEnvironment = NONE)
@Testcontainers
public class JmsTest
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsTest.class);

    @Container
    public static final GenericContainer<?> ACTIVEMQ =
        new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("rmohr/activemq"))
            .withExposedPorts(8161, 61616)
            .waitingFor(new LogMessageWaitStrategy().withRegEx(".*Apache ActiveMQ .* started.*"))
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(LOG));

    @DynamicPropertySource
    private static void ports(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.add("spring.activemq.broker-url", () -> "tcp://" + ACTIVEMQ.getHost() + ":" + ACTIVEMQ.getMappedPort(61616));
    }

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private List<String> messages = new LinkedList<>();

    @Async
    @JmsListener(destination = "out")
    public void onOut(String message)
    {
        LOG.warn("Received message from out: {}", message);
        messages.add(message);
    }

    @Test
    public void foo() throws InterruptedException
    {
        LOG.warn("Sending request");
        // Sending some message on destination 'in' to be received and answered by the listener below
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("in", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        LOG.warn("Waiting for repsonse");

        // (2)    // Try to receive response from 'out'
        //        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(2_000);
        //        Message response = jmsTemplate.receive("out");
        //        assertThat(response, notNullValue());
        
        Thread.sleep(2_000);
        assertThat(messages, hasSize(1));

    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableAsync
class TestApp
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    // (1)
    // @Async
    @JmsListener(destination = "in")
    public void onIn(String message) throws InterruptedException
    {
        LOG.warn("Received message from in: {}", message);

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("out", message);
        LOG.warn("Sent Response");

        LOG.warn("Sleeping ...");
        Thread.sleep(3_000);

        LOG.warn("Finished");
    }
}
```

Here the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmstest</artifactId>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you check the transaction handling? Could it be that `convertAndSend` does not commit the message, so the listener can not see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using transactions, the transaction won't commit until the `@JmsListener` method exits so the other consumer won't see it.

You can't use transactions for this use case.

Hence the `@Async` works because the send will be performed in a different transaction.

Comment: Are transactions enabled by default? And if so, can they be disabled?